# save a juptyer notebook with specific name within the code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter notebook that is more or a less a 'template' of how things are done.  For example the notebook is a template of say each country's economic data.  All of the plots, and analysis is standardized.

I'm looking for a way to have this saving done in a coded way rather than manually naming it myself.   Is there anyway so that if I have a variable labeled as:

```
  my_assignment = 'india'
```

I could save the notebook name as

```
  file_name =   my_assignment + todays_date

 save(file_name)
```

I code in python.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to jump to `%%javascript` to interact with `Jupyter`, which is different to the `ipython` kernel that the `python` code is sent to, e.g.:

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.notebook.copy_notebook()
```

Not sure you can copy with a specific name.
You can programmaticly rename the current notebook with:

```
Jupyter.notebook.rename(<new_name>)
```

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow and see if it works, thank you for your help!