# How to rename a Jupyter Notebook programmatically?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is there a command or any other way to rename a Jupyter Notebook in execution time?
Like appending a string created while running the notebook to the notebook's name.

Comment: you cannot rename it while running it because you need to delete the current host after you make changes and restart it because of a new ip assigned to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251312/save-a-juptyer-notebook-with-specific-name-within-the-code/44251739#44251739), one can simply call the javascript magic command and `Jupyter.notebook.rename()`.

```
%%js
Jupyter.notebook.rename(newNameString)
```