# Programmatically rename notebook in Jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I would like to rename a notebook in JupyterLab programatically.

I have tried the solution for Jupyter notebooks recommended in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251312/save-a-juptyer-notebook-with-specific-name-within-the-code), but it does not work in JupyterLab:

```
%%javascript  
Jupyter.notebook.rename(<new_name>)
```

Returns:

```
Javascript Error: jupyter is not defined
```

Is there a way to do this in JupyterLab?